# Jmeter load testing in SPA

Tags: testing, jmeter, automated-tests, single-page-application, performance-testing

I am beginner in Load testing and I am doing load testing using JMeter on a single page web application. The issue which I am facing right now that as you know  in SPA there is a single URL and page contains multiple tabs, how I can switch between the tabs using JMeter. You can see my test plan in below image.
[image]

I Know I have little knowledge, any link or guidelines are welcome as there is a limited information on google regarding SPA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not compare the load testing with automation testing. Jmeter can only trigger the request that your system is sending to server. The steps you need to do:

1. Open your URL in chrome/firefox
2. Inspect the page  or tap f12 on keyboard.
3. Go to network tab
4. Now click on the tabs you have in your webpage
5. check if there is any request being passed to server when navigating through tabs.
6. If yes, replicate the same request by adding a HTTP Request in jmeter and provide the request headers and parameters same as that of the request being passed.